# Is there a way possible to make iPad sleep / wake at specific time intervals using Apple configurator?

Tags: ios, ipad

I would need to control an iPad's sleep/wake at specific time intervals.

I know using Apple configurator helps disabling all hardware buttons and touch events too... But my motive is to make the iPad wake by 7am and sleep by 10pm.

I know apps like MokiTouch and KioskPro helps, but has limitations. Is there a way to achieve this via Apple Configurator ?